# Do damage modifiers add individually to each die of a rogue's sneak attack damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, rogue, damage

In d&d 5e
When it comes to a rogue's sneak attack, let's use a 6th level with a short bow with 18 dex as the example character(which is a 3d6 sneak attack), do you add the +4 for the bow to each individual d6 roll? Making it +16. That's kinda high, so that's why I'm asking. 
Example encounter: there's an ogre and the party's paladin is with 5 feet of it. The rogue draws and fires on it, hitting it, 1d6+4 for the shortbow, then 3d6 for the sneak attack with +4 for each d6?(the total plus being +16)

I hope that kinda makes sense. In short, do you add your dex modifier to each of your sneak attack's d6s?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### No, your attribute's modifier gets added to your total damage, not to each individual die.

*PHB, p. 196:*

> You roll the damage die **or dice**, add any modifiers, and apply the damage to your target....
>   When attacking with a weapon, you add your ability modifier -- the same modifier used for the attack roll -- to the damage.

*PHB, p. 96:*

> Once per turn, you can deal an extra 1d6 damage to one creature you hit with an attack...

Likewise, if a character had a Strength bonus of +4 to damage and was attacking with a greatsword (2d6 dmg), they would add a total of +4 to damage, not +8.

Comment: This is similar to, but not exactly the same, as a critical hit, in which you still double the damage _dice_ on an attack but only add your modifier once.

Comment: Oh I thought the ability modifier *was* doubled on a critical.